# How should I allow my members to cancel their accounts for my site?

Tags: user-interface, usability

What is the best way to allow a member to cancel their account? Should I simply have them click a cancel button on the site?

Comment: This question doesn't really have a lot to do with PHP or MySQL - and we probably need a bit more context to help you out. How much work is the user likely to have put into their account that might be lost if they cancel? At the very least you probably want an "Are you sure?" page with a checkbox, explaining what happens to their data when they cancel their account.

Comment: @Dominic Rodger a lot of content

Comment: Voting to close, this seems more like a usability question and there is a stack for that :)

Comment: @willcodejavaforfood and what is the stack?

Comment: @sneaky - oops sorry, http://ui.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a button or something that allows canceling the account with confirmation so that the user doesn't cancel by mistake. Also don't delete the account, have `deleted` flag in the users table so you can reactivate that account if needed.

Regards, Alin

Comment: There's privacy issues with not really deleting an account. A better compromise would be a "deleted" flag with a date on it, and then _really_ deleting after two weeks.